# eclipse-cdt: how to suppress some GDB commands?

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

**I have** a remote GDB stub to which my GDB debugger connects over TCP/IP under the control of Eclipse-CDT. The debugger doesn't support `set auto-solib-add` command. So when I start the application Eclipse (among other commands) sends: `-gdb-set auto-solib-add on` command to the debugger and it responds with `^error,msg="No symbol \"auto\" in current context."` That **causes launch to fail**.

I tryed to reset `Load shared library symbols automatically` flag under *Run->Debug Configurations...->C/C++ Remote Application->Debugger->Shared libraries*. But despite my expectations instead of ommiting the command it sent `-gdb-set auto-solib-add off` and it didn't work, too.

**I need** to find a way to influence Eclipse and make it suppress (or in general to gain the full control of Eclipse's behaviour) this command.

Or maybe it is possible to make GDB debugger reply with a warning instead of the error to this command?

*Eclipse-CDT: Juno, 4.1.2*
*GDB debugger: arm-elf-gdb, 6.1*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked CDT source and apparently there is no way to do it short of implementing custom GDB connector (or forking CDT).

This command is issued as a part of the "final launch sequence" - see org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.launching.FinalLaunchSequence:370. The reason it still sends the command when you uncheck the launch configuration box is to override whatever you may have in gdbinit.